# Conseguir de un dataframe filas con valores contenidos en otro dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Dispongo de un dataframe que contiene tan solo los id de cliente, el código de cliente y las fechas de los últimos pedidos de cada uno de estos clientes, y otro dataframe que contiene el resto de datos e incluye los clientes con todos sus pedidos. Querría extraer del DataFrame completo los datos de estos últimos pedidos. Lo que he hecho ha sido lo siguiente:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
today = datetime.now() ##saco la fecha de hoy

## transformo de los datos la fecha a un formato empleable
data['fecha']= pd.to_datetime(data['fecha'], format = '%Y/%m/%d')
#selecciono los datos que quiero emplear
util = data[['id','cliente','fecha','nombre','cif','direccion','geopos','pedido','articulo','descri','litros','almacen','clienombre','clietelefono1','clietelefono2']]

#convierto la agrupacion en un dataframe
list_clients = util.groupby(['id','cliente','fecha']).size().reset_index(name="count")

## variable que se modificara
flag_date = today-timedelta(days=730)

#cojo solo los clientes anteriores a esa fecha
before = list_clients[list_clients.fecha < flag_date].drop(['count'],axis = 1)

#saco solo las ultimas fechas de cada cliente en forma de dataframe
fin = before.groupby(['id','cliente'])['fecha'].max().to_frame().reset_index()

#aqui falla intentando extraer de la tabla util aquellos id de fin
util[util.id == fin.id]
```

Uso la columna id porque tiene valores únicos que se pueden emplear como clave primaria, si no debería combinar para cada consulta el código de cliente y la fecha.
El error es al buscar en útil aquellos id que tengo en el DataFrame fin, supongo por cuestiones de longitud, cómo podría solucionar esto?
Si fueran necesarios los DataFrames puedo adjuntar una muestra aunque no creo que aportasen mucho, un ejemplo de fila del DataFrame fin sería:

```py
id | cliente | fecha
---|---------|----------
42 |  32412  | 2017-02-13
```

y del DataFrame útil pues lo mismo pero añadiendo mas columnas y con valores de fechas múltiples para los clientes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si en ambos dataframes id son columnas (no indice) debes usar `pandas.Series.isin` para poder seleccionar las filas de `util` que cuyos valores en id están en `fin.id`:

```
util.loc[util.id.isin(fin.id)]
```

Ten en cuenta que `util.id == fin.id` lo que hace (o intenta) es comparar los elementos en el mismo índice de ambas series, lo cual requiere para empezar que ambas tengan los mismos elementos, pero que tampoco es lo que buscas:

> ```
> >>> import pandas as pd
>
> >>> a = pd.Series([17,  7,  5,  7])
> >>> b = pd.Series([2,  7,  5,  23])
>
> >>> a == b
> 0    False
> 1     True
> 2     True
> 3    False  # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< 7 != 23
> dtype: bool
> ```

En cambio:

> ```
> >>> a.isin(b)
> 0    False
> 1     True
> 2     True
> 3     True  # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< 7 in b
> dtype: bool
> ```

Comment: no recordaba esa función y la he empleado alguna vez, tengo que mejorar la mi método de búsqueda en la documentación, gracias.

Comment: me surge otro problema a la hora de sacar los elementos, la cuestión de hacer primero el dataframe con los id, clientes y fechas es eliminar también duplicados en lo respectivo a  pedidos, es decir dejar solamente el ultimo pedido, por eso cojo los ID, sin embargo no saco únicamente el valor de la ultima fecha, si no que saca todos, como  podría solo coger la última fecha de cada cliente?? Me refiero a este fragmento de código en concreto ```fin = before.groupby(['id','cliente'])['fecha'].max().to_frame().reset_index()```